# Obtain x from $\exp(-x) \cdot x=y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\exp(-x)  \cdot x=y$$

I want to obtain $x$ from this equation ($x=f(y)$). $x$ and $y$ are positive. I've spent now some time on it and I don't know how to do this. I've tried to use logarithms here, but I can't get a single $x$.

Is this a difficult equation or did I forget about an easy method to solve it?

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: I don't know how to write $x$ in terms of $y$, but differentiating both sides after taking logorithm gives $x$ in terms  of $y$ and $y'$.

Comment: Note that there are no solutions to the equation if $y > 1/e$, exactly one solution if $y = 1/e$ (namely $x=1$), two solutions if $0 < y < 1/e$, and one solution if $y < 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a trascendental equation, so you cannot explicitly solve for $x$ unless you know something about the Lambert W function.

Cheers!

Edit: in Mathematica this is noted as the "ProductLog" function.

Comment: I've tried to calculate this in Maple and it returns LambertW. Unfortunately I have no idea what Lambert W is, therefore I can't even think about using it.

Comment: Hi! You might want to use this alternative. Consider the Newton-Raphson iteration to solve numerically the equation $F(x) = e^{-x} x - y = 0$, for every value of $y$ (this gives you $x_k = f(y_k)$ for every iteration $k$). You may obtain a reasonably good approximation to the function you seek.

Comment: I've just thought about that :).